# How to point to endpoints for an API in BlueMix?

Tags: load-balancing, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, ibm-api-management, cast-iron

We have deployed our flows in Cast Iron Virtual Appliances. There are 2 Virtual Appliances which will be acting in Active-Active mode.

I have created a Secure gateway and added a destination with the Virtual Appliance-1 IP. The cloud host of Appliance-1 is configured as Proxy in the API which I am able to consume.

My question here is if I add another destination to the Secure Gateway with Appliance-2 IP and get another cloud host URL .
Then how do I configure the Cloud Host-2 URL also as API endpoint?

I need to balance the load between the 2 Cloud Host URL's.

Kindly suggest what needs to be done in this case as I see we can associate only 1 Proxy URL as API Endpoint (Under Resource -> Implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding that Cloud Host for Appliance-1 is configured as Proxy in API Management on Bluemix and you would like add another Cloud Host for Appliance-2.  With this setup, you would like to configure to balance the load between the 2 Cloud Hosts.  That feature is not available in Secure Gateway or API Management.

Comment: You can make Bluemix enhancement suggestions on the Bluemix Ideas at the following URL: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas